# How to output error message if user inputs numbers out of range?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, range

My objective is to not allow the user to enter a weight that is < 0 or > 400.If they do, output an error message in red to div#results and ‘return’ out of the function. I set an if statement but that only seems to work when the user doesn't select a radio button (discount).

```
function calcTotal() {

    var msg;
    var weight = parseInt( document.getElementById("weight").value );
    var total;
    var totalAfterDiscount;

    if( weight >= 0 && weight <= 150 ) {

        total = weight * 20 
    }   
    else if( weight >150 && weight <= 300 ) {

        total = weight * 15 
    }   
    else if( weight >300 && weight <= 400 ) {

        total = weight * 10 
    }

    if( weight < 0 || weight > 400) {

        msg = "<div>Weight is out of range!</div>";
    }

    if( document.getElementById("50%").checked == true ) {

        totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.50;
        msg = "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
    }

    if( document.getElementById("25%").checked == true ) {

        totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.25;
        msg = "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
    }

    if( document.getElementById("none").checked == true ) {

        totalAfterDiscount = total;
        msg = "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
    }
    // send output to browser

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting the msg variable
concatinate your error messages to msg variable try this

```
    function calcTotal() {
    var msg;
    var weight = parseInt( document.getElementById("weight").value );
    var total;
var totalAfterDiscount;

if( weight >= 0 && weight <= 150 ) {

    total = weight * 20 
}   
else if( weight >150 && weight <= 300 ) {

    total = weight * 15 
}   
else if( weight >300 && weight <= 400 ) {

    total = weight * 10 
}

if( weight < 0 || weight > 400) {

    msg = "<div>Weight is out of range!</div>";
}

if( document.getElementById("50%").checked == true ) {

    totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.50;
    msg += "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
}

if( document.getElementById("25%").checked == true ) {

    totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.25;
    msg += "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
}

if( document.getElementById("none").checked == true ) {

    totalAfterDiscount = total;
    msg += "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
}
// send output to browser

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
```

}

even if you want to show single message at a time you can try this

```
    function calcTotal() {
    var msg;
    var weight = parseInt( document.getElementById("weight").value );
    var total;
var totalAfterDiscount;

if( weight >= 0 && weight <= 150 ) {

    total = weight * 20 
}   
else if( weight >150 && weight <= 300 ) {

    total = weight * 15 
}   
else if( weight >300 && weight <= 400 ) {

    total = weight * 10 
}

if( weight < 0 || weight > 400) {

    msg = "<div>Weight is out of range!</div>";
   return;
}

if( document.getElementById("50%").checked == true ) {

    totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.50;
    msg = "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
    return;
}

if( document.getElementById("25%").checked == true ) {

    totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.25;
    msg = "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
    return;
}

if( document.getElementById("none").checked == true ) {

    totalAfterDiscount = total;
    msg = "<div> Your total cost is: $" + totalAfterDiscount + "</div>";
    return;
}
// send output to browser

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this? Outputting a msg for each statement seems wrong.

Comment: then try with first one and in start of every messages write <br> then every message will be shown in new line

Comment: if still you are getting the problem post your code on jsfiddle i will give the solved one :)

Comment: Nvm. I figured it out!